# Global parameters for hadoop in oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hadoop2

**Note:** I am new into Hadoop ecosystem

Right now, I am trying to create some global variables in my oozie workflow (in order not to repeat my parameters). Since I use the Cloudera distribution I tried to see if we can do that http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Global-parameters-to-oozie-workflow/m-p/24198#M911 but I got no answer (I think this is not possible).

Therefore, now I am trying to see other solutions for global parameters:
- use an HBase Table or a HDFS Hive Table in order to save the global parameters (this solution may have inpact on performances...)
- use shell scripts for each action and have a shell script imported into each one of the scripts.

If you have other solutions for this problem, please let me know. I just want to know what is the best solution/ how should I do it.

Thank you!

Comment: [It was a bug and it has been fixed](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2339)